# Реакт-роутер, редирект

Tags: react-router

Подскажите, почему не рендерит компонент при редиректе?

```
<Switch>
{ isLogin? 
  <Route path="/Info" component={Info} />
 :<Route path="/Login" component={Login} /> }
<Redirect from="*" to="/Login" />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Какая ошибка в консоли?

Comment: @entithat Только предупреждение, якобы я Redirect не использую, могу дать ссылку на репозиторий, если так проще будет)
     Line 7:  'Redirect' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars